# Como alterar o horário do Linux pela linha de comando?

Tags: linux

Consigo ver o horário do Linux pela linha de comando assim:

```
 >date 
 Qua Mai 25 14:49:58 BRT 2016
```

Mas agora eu preciso alterar o horário do Linux pela linha de comando, pois, como uso um servidor Linux, só tenho acesso via SSH.

Como alterar o horário do Linux pela linha de comando?

**Nota**: Sei que não está no escopo do site fazer perguntas sobre sistema operacional, mas como se trata de um problema relacionado à programação postei aqui. Todos os meus sistemas estavam com a data errada por conta disso,  mas acabei conseguindo resolver com a solução dada na resposta (Grato pela resposta).

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha lido a parte do SSH. Ignore a resposta removida

Comment: Não acho que esteja fora do escopo, acreditava que seria um famoso voto por vingança mas acaba de receber outro -1. Seria caso de recorrer ao META?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não dei o -1, mas votei para fechar, não me leve a mal, mas só porque você tem o problema, não quer dizer que ele esteja no escopo(foi o que deu a entender do comentário). Eu acho que  a pergunta cabe ao superuser.

Comment: Não fui eu que deu -1, entretanto, eu votei para fechar como fora de escopo, sua dúvida esta mais direcionada a configuração do sistema do que em algo relacionado com programação, se estive querendo saber como alterar a hora do servido via shell script até seria valido, talvez [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) possa ser um lugar adequado para pegunta sobre comandos do terminal.

Comment: Até deve estar pensar que fui eu @Wallace Maxters, mas não. Até concordo que não se deve dar uma resposta sem ter a certeza de que pode dar certo. Acho que é uma pergunta tão legitima como outra qql

Comment: @drmcarvalho esse site da rede eu nem conhecia, ele parece ainda mais indicado que o superuser.

Comment: @Miguel aliás, sua resposta estava correta ;)

Comment: Mas a sua merece mais, mutio mais completa e segura. Eu respondi sem testar, não tinha a certeza

Comment: Ainda não entendo o porque dos pontos negativos se é uma pergunta que pode ajudar muitos programadores que gerenciam seus  servidores no Amazon por exemplo. Merece +1

Comment: Você pode substituir o arquivo `/etc/localtime'  pelos arquivos da pasta `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, eles são responsáveis pelo fuso horario, (caso queira alterar apenas a hora)

Comment: (Atrasado) Para a maioria dos comandos UNIX/Linux a opção `--help` traz o básico de ajuda relacionado a esse comando. Exemplo: `date --help`

Answer (score 10):

Tinha feito uma resposta, mas era alteração por terminal, falha minha. Bom pra alterar por linha de comando no SSH é bem fácil também.

**Mudar hora** (ex. 10 horas e 52 minutos: 10:00:00):

```
date +%T -s "10:52:00"
```

**Mudar data** (ex.: 25 de Outubro de 2016, 18 horas):

```
date -s "25 OCT 2016 18:00:00"
```

E vou deixar também a opção do [@Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5749/miguel) que postou em uma resposta a pouco tempo, mas infelizmente apagou.

Alterar data e hora:

```
sudo date –s "25 DEZ 2016 15:04:00"
```

Alterar apenas hora:

```
sudo date +%T -s "15:04:00"
```

Basicamente `sudo` trabalha com o comando `date –set="STRING"`

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer um script que usa o comando "[doas](https://github.com/Duncaen/OpenDoas)" que roda comandos de root sem senha, apenas consegui acerta a hora

```
site='https://www.horariodebrasilia.org/'
dia=$(curl -s "$site" | grep -Poh '(?<=\<h3 id="dia-topo"\>).*(?=\</h3\>)')
hora=$(curl -s "$site" | grep -Poh '(?<=\<p id="relogio"\>).*(?=\</p\>)')

# echo "$dia"
# echo "$hora"

doas date +%T -s "$hora"
```

As opções do grep são:

```
-P ........... perl regex (expressão regular avançada)
-o ........... imprime somente o padrão buscado
-h ........... não imprime nome de arquivo
(?<=padrão) .. positive look behind 
(?=padrão)  .. positive look ahead
```

Pensei ser também possível usar a biblioteca python Beautifulsoup4 para pegar os valores e usar a biblioteca sys ou algo similar para setar a hora certa no sistema.